# XML into the PL SQL navigator

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I want to install the library of XML first but I don't know which one and secondly I want to generate a XML file from a table in SQL navigator.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more details about what you are trying to do. Include a [MRE] with details of what data is being input and what you expect the XML output to be.

Comment: Please, clarify your question, you have tagged it as about xml, plsql and Oracle, but it seems you are asking about installation details of a specific product, SQL Navigator by Quest software: https://www.quest.com/products/sql-navigator/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.